# More efficient way of taking averages over multiple lists

Tags: r

I have some data where I use the `rsample` package to create rolling windows (I use the `iris` data set here). The `rolling_iris` dataset contains a number of lists.

I would like to compute the `min`, `max`, `mean` and `sd` of each of the lists. That is in `split` 1 compute the `min` across the first 4 columns etc. I originally do this by mapping over the splits and using `pivot_longer` to rearrange the data then computing the statistics, finally using `pivot_wider` to get the data back into the original form. This is quite slow.

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

iris
rolling_iris <- rsample::rolling_origin(iris, initial = 10, assess = 1, cumulative = FALSE, skip = 0)

rolling_iris_statistics <- map(rolling_iris$splits, ~analysis(.x) %>%
      pivot_longer(cols = 1:4) %>%
      mutate(
        min = min(value),
        max = max(value),
        mean = mean(value),
        sd = sd(value)
      ) %>% 
        group_by(name) %>% 
        mutate(rowID = row_number()) %>% 
        pivot_wider(names_from = name, values_from = value)
    )
```

I would like to map over each of the lists and compute the above statistics. Then once this is done scale the `analysis`  by the following function.

```
Scale_Me <- function(x){
  (x - min(x)) / (max(x) - min(x))
}
```

Additional:

```
rolling_iris_analysis <- map(rolling_iris$splits, ~analysis(.x))
rolling_iris_assessment <- map(rolling_iris$splits, ~assessment(.x))
```

EDIT:

I managed to compute the following (I am not sure if it is "faster")

```
analysis <- map(rolling_iris$splits, ~analysis(.x))
map(analysis, ~select(., c(1:4)) %>% as.matrix %>% mean())
```

Answer (score 0):

The below code subsets into each sub data frame. So, `rolling_iris_dfs` is a list of data frames. Then, you can iterate over each data frame and compute statistics.

```
rolling_iris_dfs <- map(seq(1, length(rolling_iris[[1]])), ~rolling_iris[[1]][[.x]]$data) 

rolling_iris_stats <- map(rolling_iris_dfs, ~analysis(.x) %>%
      pivot_longer(cols = 1:4) %>%
      mutate(
        min = min(value),
        max = max(value),
        mean = mean(value),
        sd = sd(value)
      ) %>% 
        group_by(name) %>% 
        mutate(rowID = row_number()) %>% 
        pivot_wider(names_from = name, values_from = value)
    )
```